# Backtracking problem managing figures on a board

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I have a problem which must be solved using backtracking, but i cannot figure out how to do it. So, i have a board and some figures (rectangles and squares). I know the dimensions for every figure and the column where it starts. But the problem is that I have to manage them so they will not overlapping each other. Here is an exemple of photo on how they should look like:

[image]

I repeat, i know the position(column) where the figure must start and the dimension. For example: i know A1 will start at second column, will have 2 rows height and 6 columns width. I just can't think on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you written anything so far? Consider a tree-searching algorithm. Build out potential figure placements via some algorithm and when you get to a point where a certain branch fails, go back up the tree and take another branch. Repeat until you find a solution.

Comment: I understand the theory. I dont know how to implement it. Let's say i am starting from to top to bottom and always check if the figure can fit in the tested place. I do not know what i should do when I find a figure that do not fit.

Comment: One way would be recursion. Write a recursive function that takes a partial solution and extends it by one. If successful, recursively attempt to extend all possible next states. If not, return (thus popping a stack frame and backtracking up the tree). If you reach a solution then you have a solution, if you run out of possible states then there is none. If  you know how to write "recursive" functions as iterative functions, then you could also do that; e.g., push partial states into a stack instead and pop bad states.